# quasi random assignment in data.frame using alphabetic order of a string variable

Tags: r

My data looks more or less like that.

```
df <- 
data.frame(ID=rep(c(1:8),each=4),ID_code=rep(c("ab","xy","zz","ee","bl","gr","au","ie"),each=4),Seq=rep(c('A','AM','B','BM')),Group=rep(c('A','B','C','A'),each=4))
```

I have three groups in my data. For one group i need to get a randoms assignment. I would like to make it depending on the variable ID_code. I already found percent_rank, which makes it possible to split the data into four subgroups by taking 4 times 25%.

This code works, but it is not very neat.

```
df$TestSeq[df$Group=='C'] <- 'DS'

df$TestSeq[df$Group=='C' & percent_rank(df$ID_code[df$Group=='C'])<0.25 & df$Seq=='A'] <- 'MS'
df$TestSeq[df$Group=='C' & percent_rank(df$ID_code[df$Group=='C'])<0.25 & df$Seq=='AM'] <- 'SS'
df$TestSeq[df$Group=='C' & 0.25<=percent_rank(df$ID_code[df$Group=='C'])& percent_rank(df$ID_code[df$Group=='C'])<0.5 & df$Seq=='B'] <- 'MS'
df$TestSeq[df$Group=='C' & 0.25<=percent_rank(df$ID_code[df$Group=='C'])& percent_rank(df$ID_code[df$Group=='C'])<0.5 & df$Seq=='BM'] <- 'SS'
df$TestSeq[df$Group=='C' & 0.5<=percent_rank(df$ID_code[df$Group=='C'])& percent_rank(df$ID_code[df$Group=='C'])<0.75 & df$Seq=='AM'] <- 'MS'
df$TestSeq[df$Group=='C' & 0.5<=percent_rank(df$ID_code[df$Group=='C'])& percent_rank(df$ID_code[df$Group=='C'])<0.75 & df$Seq=='A'] <- 'SS'
df$TestSeq[df$Group=='C' & 0.75<=percent_rank(df$ID_code[df$Group=='C']) & df$Seq=='B'] <- 'MS'
df$TestSeq[df$Group=='C' & 0.75<=percent_rank(df$ID_code[df$Group=='C']) & df$Seq=='BM'] <- 'SS'
```

Maybe there is also a shorter code? I tried to pipe it. But i don't make it.

```
df %>% 
  filter(Group=='C') %>%
  mutate( TestSeq = case_when(
              percent_rank(ID_code)<0.25 & df$Seq=='A'  ~ 'MS',
              percent_rank(ID_code)<0.25 & df$Seq=='AM' ~ 'SS',
              percent_rank(ID_code)<0.5  &df$Seq=='AM' & 0.25 <= percent_rank(ID_code)  ~ 'MS', 
              TRUE ~ 'DS'
            )
    )
```

Comment: Can you include the desired output?  I'm not sure what you did & didn't like from that 2nd snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @wibeasley i found the solution, although not short it is quite good readable:

```
df1 <- df %>% 
  filter(Group=='C') %>%
  mutate( TestSeq = case_when(
              percent_rank(ID_code)<0.25  & Seq=='A'                                    ~ 'MS',
              percent_rank(ID_code)<0.25  & Seq=='AM'                                   ~ 'SS',
              percent_rank(ID_code)<0.5   & Seq=='AM'  & 0.25 <= percent_rank(ID_code)  ~ 'MS',
              percent_rank(ID_code)<0.5   & Seq=='A'   & 0.25 <= percent_rank(ID_code)  ~ 'SS',
              percent_rank(ID_code)<0.75  & Seq=='B'   & 0.5  <= percent_rank(ID_code)  ~ 'MS',
              percent_rank(ID_code)<0.75  & Seq=='BM'  & 0.5  <= percent_rank(ID_code)  ~ 'SS',
                                            Seq=='BM'  & 0.75 <= percent_rank(ID_code)  ~ 'MS',
                                            Seq=='B'   & 0.75 <= percent_rank(ID_code)  ~ 'SS',
              TRUE ~ 'DS'
            )
    )


full_join(df,df1)
```

Considering all the hints from wibeasley, i changed the code to this:

```
df1a <- df %>% 
  #filter(Group=='C') %>%
  mutate( 
    code_rank = case_when(
      Group=='C' ~ percent_rank(ID_code)
    )
  ) %>%
  mutate(
    TestSeq = case_when(
      is.na(Group) | (Group!='C') ~ '0', # Or whatever

      Seq=='A'  & (code_rank < .25)    ~ 'MS',
      Seq=='A'  & (code_rank < .50)    ~ 'SS',
      Seq=='A'  & (code_rank < Inf)    ~ 'DS',

      Seq=='AM' & (code_rank < .25)    ~ 'SS',
      Seq=='AM' & (code_rank < .50)    ~ 'MS',
      Seq=='AM' & (code_rank < Inf)    ~ 'DS',

      Seq=='B'  & (code_rank < .50)    ~ 'DS',
      Seq=='B'  & (code_rank < .75)    ~ 'MS',
      Seq=='B'  & (code_rank < Inf)    ~ 'SS',

      Seq=='BM' & (code_rank < .50)    ~ 'DS',
      Seq=='BM' & (code_rank < .75)    ~ 'SS',
      Seq=='BM' & (code_rank < Inf)    ~ 'MS'
    )
  ) #%>% 
  dplyr::select(-code_rank)
```

However, this has one problem. The code_rank is calculated from all IDs, but should only be calculated from Group=='C'. Is there a way to put a filter into mutate/into case_when? 
I also noticed that the percent_rank is calculated be 4/7 because i have duplicates. My new solution:

```
df1a <- df %>% 
  filter(Group=='C') %>%
  filter(!duplicated(ID)) %>%
  mutate( 
    code_rank = percent_rank(ID_code)
    )

df <- left_join(df,df1a)

df <- df %>% group_by(ID) %>% fill(code_rank) #get code_rank in all rows

#View(df)
df1b <- df %>% 
  filter(Group=='C') %>%
  mutate(
    TestSeq = case_when(
      Seq=='A'  & (code_rank < .25)    ~ 'MS',
      Seq=='A'  & (code_rank < .50)    ~ 'SS',
      Seq=='A'  & (code_rank < Inf)    ~ 'DS',

      Seq=='AM' & (code_rank < .25)    ~ 'SS',
      Seq=='AM' & (code_rank < .50)    ~ 'MS',
      Seq=='AM' & (code_rank < Inf)    ~ 'DS',

      Seq=='B'  & (code_rank < .25)    ~ 'DS',
      Seq=='B'  & (code_rank < .75)    ~ 'MS',
      Seq=='B'  & (code_rank < Inf)    ~ 'SS',

      Seq=='BM' & (code_rank < .50)    ~ 'DS',
      Seq=='BM' & (code_rank < .75)    ~ 'SS',
      Seq=='BM' & (code_rank < Inf)    ~ 'MS'
    )
  ) 

df <- select(left_join(df,df1b),-code_rank)
```

Answer (score 1):

The error from your third snippet is because `df` was explicitly in the `mutate()` statement.  It has 32 rows, while only 8 rows are fed to `mutate()` (because you filtered on `Group`).

```
library(magrittr)
library(rlang)  # For the `.data` pronoun

df %>% 
  filter(Group=='C') %>%
  mutate( 
    TestSeq = case_when(
      percent_rank(ID_code)<0.25 & Seq=='A'  ~ 'MS',
      percent_rank(ID_code)<0.25 & Seq=='AM' ~ 'SS',
      percent_rank(ID_code)<0.5  & Seq=='AM' & 0.25 <= percent_rank(ID_code)  ~ 'MS', 
      TRUE ~ 'DS'
    )
  )
```

If you're worried about naming collisions with `Seq`, use the [`.data` pronoun](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/tidyeval-data.html) from the rlang package.

```
df %>% 
  filter(Group=='C') %>%
  mutate( 
    TestSeq = case_when(
      percent_rank(ID_code)<0.25 & .data$Seq=='A'  ~ 'MS',
      percent_rank(ID_code)<0.25 & .data$Seq=='AM' ~ 'SS',
      percent_rank(ID_code)<0.5  & .data$Seq=='AM' & 0.25 <= percent_rank(ID_code)  ~ 'MS', 
      TRUE ~ 'DS'
    )
  )
```

Result:

```
  ID ID_code Seq Group TestSeq
1  3      zz   A     C      DS
2  3      zz  AM     C      DS
3  3      zz   B     C      DS
4  3      zz  BM     C      DS
5  7      au   A     C      MS
6  7      au  AM     C      SS
7  7      au   B     C      DS
8  7      au  BM     C      DS
```

Here are two more sources about `.data`:
(a) [a dplyr vignette](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html#different-data-sets) and (b) ['data masks' in adv-r](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/evaluation.html#data-masks).

Comment: Sometimes it's the easy things. And you just don't see them! df in mutate. OMG. Sry

Answer (score 1):

I understand the goal better, and see your answer.  It sounds like you want it to be more concise, which is possible if you leverage the waterfall property of `dplyr::case_when()` (i.e., if the execution gets to the *k*th line, you can be sure that the previous *k*-1 lines are false.  In allows you to omit the lower bound for each line.

For each value of `Seq`, I'd probably still put the 'DS' assignment.  Even though it's redundant with the final line, the pattern is probably easier to maintain & debug if so unexpected values don't fall through the cracks.  This slight execution inefficiency is probably worth the robustness.

```
df1a <- df %>% 
  filter(Group=='C') %>%
  mutate( 
    code_rank   = percent_rank(ID_code),
    TestSeq = case_when(
      Seq=='A'  & (code_rank < .25)    ~ 'MS',
      Seq=='A'  & (code_rank < .50)    ~ 'SS',
      Seq=='A'  & (code_rank < Inf)    ~ 'DS',

      Seq=='AM' & (code_rank < .25)    ~ 'SS',
      Seq=='AM' & (code_rank < .50)    ~ 'MS',
      Seq=='AM' & (code_rank < Inf)    ~ 'DS',

      Seq=='B'  & (code_rank < .25)    ~ 'DS',
      Seq=='B'  & (code_rank < .75)    ~ 'MS',
      Seq=='B'  & (code_rank < Inf)    ~ 'DS',

      Seq=='BM' & (code_rank < .50)    ~ 'DS',
      Seq=='BM' & (code_rank < .75)    ~ 'SS',
      Seq=='BM' & (code_rank < Inf)    ~ 'DS',

      TRUE ~ 'DS'
    )
  ) %>% 
  dplyr::select(-code_rank)

df2 <- full_join(df, df1a)
```

Finally, if you want to avoid the join, I think you can drop the `filter()` and `full_join()` statements, and add the following line to the top of `case_when()`:

```
is.na(Group) | (Group=='C')   ~ '0' # Or whatever
```

If you do keep the join, a `left_join()` might be a better fit.  And with either, I'd explicitly state the columns you're joining on.  As your program gorws over time, you don't want new columns to be accidentally used to join.